# Staggered color behing wrapping text

Tags: css

I am looking to create the effect shown in the following image:

[image]

Where the black background behind the text staggers, rather than creating a black box when the string wraps. Can this be achieved with just CSS on a dynamic string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ebn7z/) is how you do it. The basic idea is to wrap each word in a separate div and nest those divs within another div with a width that wraps the inline divs.

```
<style>
    .foo {
      display: inline;
      background-color: #000;
      color: #fff;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .wrapper {
      width: 100px;
    }
</style>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="foo">Here </div><div class="foo">is </div><div class="foo">some </div><div class="foo">text </div><div class="foo">exciting </div><div class="foo">isn't </div><div class="foo">it </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Not just CSS, less than ideal in a dynamic situation?!

Comment: In a dynamic situation you can use a percentage width on the wrapper.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "dynamic situation"?

Answer (score 3):

This is actually the default behaviour for inline elements, such as span.
The following code should have this effect.

```
<span style="background-color: black; color: white">EYES ON<br/>FILM</span>
```

Note that the `<br/>` is there for illustrative purposes, it will also work if the text is wrapped by the browser.
If you need to do this for a div, make sure to set the `display: inline` style on it.

Comment: Odd, they are h5 I am trying to wrap, but have display: inline; on?!

Comment: Strike that, I notices the <br> tag. Is there no way to do this with just CSS?

Comment: Very strange, there may be some other style interfering, because this works (see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQFaT/)) fine for me in all browsers. As Christopher Tokar suggests, you can wrap each word in a div, but it seems so much less elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

http://jsfiddle.net/wxDa7/

```
<style>
    #a 
    { 
        width:50px; 
        font-size:20px; 
        line-height: 90%; 
        text-transform:uppercase; 
    }
    #a .b 
    {
         background-color:black; 
         color:white;  
    } 
</style>
<div id="a">
      <span class="b">Test&nbsp; test&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

This autobreaks at a defined width. Use %nbsp; to get the extra space after the text.

Answer (score 0):

It works putting the text inside a `<span>` inside a `<p>`, or using the Teletype Text Element (`<tt>`), or `<code>` tag.

**`<tt>` is not accepted in HTML5**.

Example jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gmDWP/